# UiApp, FlexTable.removeRow()

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a UiApp, that has a FlexTable, each row represents a locations. These locations are marked by checkboxes, the users seletc them and when they execute the save function I'd like to update the table so that only the selected rows remain.

```
...
var checkbox_sorszam = []
var rows_to_del = []

  for(var i = 0; i < locations_data.length; i++)
  {
    if(e.parameter['checkboxischecked'+i] == 'true')
    {
      location_list.push(e.parameter['checkbox_value_'+i]);
      checkbox_sorszam.push(i)
    }
    if(e.parameter['checkboxischecked'+i] == 'false')
    {
      rows_to_del.push(i)
    }   
  }
```

This way I have the index of rows that need to be deleted

```
for (var d=0;d<rows_to_del.length;++d)
  {
    Logger.log(rows_to_del[d])
    tarhely_table.removeRow(rows_to_del[d])        
  }
```

I get an 'Invalid value: row' error. I tried parseInt(rows_to_del[d]), same results. I prefer not creating a new table but to delete rows which the users did't select.

Comment: what do you have in Logger.log(rows_to_del[d]) ?

Comment: [1.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0] the row indexes of rows that are not selected, (1st row, 2-3rd slected with indexes:0, 2, 3)

Comment: So I think in theory it should work as the table rows are also 0 indexed.There are 13 rows, 0-12 is in rows_to_del[] if all is selected. Of course I tried tarhely_table.removeRow(1) for example. Same error.

Comment: thanks for the info. It seems indeed it should be valid... I'll try this on a test and let you know if I find something later. no time right now ;-/

Comment: Thanks Serge, it's not too important, but would be helpful if it worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Google Apps Script Class UiApp is deprecated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider deleting the rows in reverse.

Let's say your table initially has 3 rows in it:

> 0: red
>   1: green
>   2: blue

User selects row 1, so you plan on deleting rows 0 and 2.

First time though the loop, you delete row 0.  Now your table is:

> 0: green
>   1: blue

Second time through the loop, you delete row 2

There is no row 2....

Starting over, let's say user selects row 2: blue, so you plan on deleting 0 and 1.

First time through the loop, you delete row 0, now your table is:

> 0: green
>   1: blue

Second time through the loop, you delete row 1, now your table is:

> 0: green

User is confused.

Comment: Brilliant demonstration of simple logic ;-) thanks - I love the very neat style...upvoted of course.

Comment: Thank you Nexus, it works perfect! I just added a sort function before removing rows: rows_to_del.sort(function(a,b){return b - a}).